# How could RaspberryPi HDMI Port be changed with terminal code?

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display, raspberry-pi-os, terminal

[image: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B]

When both HDMI ports connect two separate displays, I want to change the HDMI port directly from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 with console(terminal) code. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: to clarify ... you want to swap the output in software?

Comment: yes, I would like to swap hdmi output (e.g 0 to 1) in software, with terminal code. Or should I add any code line in config.txt?